# Why do people use the term "six figure sum" to mean "at least one million dollars"?

Tags: etymology, slang

In Australia at least, a "six figure sum" is synonymous with an amount over $1,000,000.

The last time I checked, `1000000` had seven digits in it.

To quote [a recent article in Melbourne's highest circulating newspaper](http://www.heraldsun.com.au/news/opinion/channel-9s-tawdry-tangle/news-story/da4f6023386dd555c7c17f4d2e8383c5):

> Has Channel 9, a publicly listed company, paid at least a six-figure sum, or several million dollars to get is (sic) employees out of Lebanon?

Comment: I've never heard this (in the US). Incidentally, one million = 10^6, but that yields seven digits, as you say.

Comment: They do so because they never joined this site and asked what a six figure sum is. They should.

Comment: @vicky this is not a duplicate. I edited the question to reference a recent online article that shows this specific (incorrect) usage. Perhaps it is endemic to Australia.

Comment: I think that this is just a mistake in the article.  You'll need more evidence than this to say that it's "synonymous with an amount over $1,000,000 in Australia"

Comment: Also it's not clear from that article whether the reporter means *"a six-figure sum, or several million dollars (which are two different things)"* or *"a six-figure sum, or several million dollars (which is another way of saying a six-figure sum)"*

Comment: Here in the USA references to people earning 6 figures are common, but we never understand that to mean a million or more.

Comment: Why? Because they're wrong, and don't know any better.

Comment: I read the quoted article as saying "[they] paid *at least* a six-figure sum, or [sometimes as much as] several million dollars".

Comment: @max well, I can say that I've only ever heard it used this way - I'll hunt for more references. Regarding the "or" ambiguity, there is no chance they meant "$100K", which would be peanuts given the scenario.

Comment: Anyone who thinks a 6-figure sum means 1,000,000 or more has figures confused with zeroes.

Comment: hi @Bohemian dude.  it's just a case of "you're wrong" here bud.  i lived in Aus. for years and Australians are not particularly silly or illiterate.  everyone there in business etc. uses the ordinary phrase "six figures" (meaning 'about $200,000 - $500,000'') the same as in every other English speaking country. It's totally commonplace.  (1) you're interpreting the text wrong as Max and Trevor point out (2) it's ***just a typo*** - an utterly commonplace "so what?" occurance in newspapers (3) *"I'll hunt for more references"* you'd be wasting your time, but go for it.

Comment: Just FWIW you say *"... would be peanuts given the scenario"*.  Nah, a few hundred thousand dollars, perhaps 1/2 million dollars, (i.e "six figures") is a Lot of Money and could trivially achieve the thing under discussion.   Dude ***It's just a typo*** - "just a typo"s come up often on this site, honest it's nothing more than that.  They tend to generate a huge amount of discussion but it's just nothing other than a typo or hurried writing; typos and miswritings *are the norm* in newspapers.  Ask 20 Aussies working in high paid fields , they use "six figures" like anyone else in the world.

Answer (score 2):

"Six figures" usually refers to amounts over 100,000, not amounts over 1,000,000.

Yesterday's question on [what six figures means](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323803/jane-makes-over-six-figures-how-much-money-does-she-make/323875#323875) is related.

Answer (score -1):

I would say that "Over 6 figures" must mean 7 or more (1,000,000). Referring not so much to 100,001 being "over 6 figures" in value, but the actual number of figures being the subject of the saying.

sorry for broken grammar, I'm seconds from finishing work :P